# Cannot find windows 8 option after installing ubuntu

Tags: windows-8

I succeded in installing  ubuntu 12.04 alongside win 8 bt after that laptop directly booted to ubuntu without a grub selection menu.So I installed boot-repair which gave me grub with only ubuntu and memtest choices and not windows 8.Also while installing ubuntu it asked me that something was not configured do you want to continue and i ignored and agreed.Please help to get windows 8 back.Also I cannot see my hard drivein Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: from Ubuntu, please install gparted, open it and post a link to a screenshot

Comment: You can upload the screenshot at http://www.imgur.com and edit your question and **put the link in the question above.**

Answer (score 1):

You have erased Win8 partition according to your image :(

Comment: Yeah, you would see more partitions instead of "unallocated" if W8 was still there, unfortuantely. W8 would show up either as NTFS or "unrecognized" partition type, but all of the partitions listed in your screenshot are ext-type partitions, upon which you will never find a working Windows installation (unless MS decides to move to a non-proprietary FS type someday).

Comment: but i installed ubuntu alongside also made a partition then why such case....?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me

-Boot from windows8 Install disc > Click Next > click Repair your computer > click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Command Prompt

type > bootrec /fixmbr (writes mbr but does not overwrite partition table)
type > bootrec /fixboot (writes new boot sector to system partition)
type > bootrec /scanos (scans for other OS’s that you might want to add to bcd
type > bootrec /rebuildbcd (scans for other OS’s, unlike rebuildbcd it allows you to select the OS’s you want to add to bcd)
Reboot

good luck!!!